# Magento 2 - Self referring canonical for custom page

Tags: magento2, seo, canonical

How do i add a self referring canonical to a custom page layout manufacturerers_index_index ?

The above wont work because the url could be one of many i.e. the layout is inherited by multiple different pages i.e. WWW.ABC.com/manufacturer1, WWW.ABC.com/manufacturer2 etc

Or is there a simple way to add the canonical to all pages and override the canonical setting in configuration > catalog > SEO settings ?